# Can someone provide a tabbed view plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, uitabview

Should be light in size and have an acceptable UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

[jQuery UI tabs](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/)

Also take a look at

[jFlow 1.2 – The Ultra-lightweight Fluid Content Slider for jQuery](http://www.gimiti.com/kltan/wordpress/?p=46)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the official [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin which has a [Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) widget, and is [*highly*](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming) [customizable](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

See the [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [jqueryUI](http://www.jqueryUI.com)

Dan

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html) has a nice lightweight tab widget.

The jquery-ui tabs are ok but a little heavy with the js and css.